# get git tags from python 3.x on windows

Tags: python, git, powershell

I have tried but an unable to complete a seemingly trivial task in Python 3.8 on Windows 10.
In PowerShell (core) this takes me less than 2 minutes to write :

```
repo = "../micropython/git"
return (&git --git-dir=$repo describe --tags $(git --git-dir=$repo rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1))
```

result is 'v1.12' (or whatever the newest version) that branch is at

Using python I'm not able to get any results at all, after spending too much time on this assumed oneliner

tried:

```
# 1 feeding it the commandline as text 
cmd_str = "git --git-dir=../micropython/.git describe --tags $(git --git-dir=../micropython/.git rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1)"
subprocess.run( cmdstr , capture_output=True,shell=True)

#2 splitting the cmdline using shlex.split 

command_line = """
git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags=\"v[0-9].[0-9]*\" --max-count=1)
"""
cmd = shlex.split(command_line)
x = subprocess.run( cmd, capture_output=True )
print(x)

# 3 using the 'gitpython' library
would not even import .... : see issue below

#4..20 
many variations of the above
```

https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/970

so the simplest way for me as a developer seems to be to just to shell out from python to powershell, ( as that is cross platform) and take the dependency.

However I started this in python rather than powershell as the script is intended for the python community (and as a learning experience), surely there is a way to do this in a more pylike , and perhaps even somewhat elegant way ?

Versions:

- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1]
- git version 2.24.1.windows.2
- Python 3.8.1

Comment: Powershell is cross-platform? Maybe if installed—seems simpler to use the simplest possible syntax. Run one subproc for the subshell, then splice in the results to the main one.

Comment: Yes, pwsh 6.x , aka **PowerShell Core** runs on a lot fo different architectures.
See [Powershell Core](https://github.com/powershell/powershell#-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... surely there is a way to do this in a more pylike , and perhaps even somewhat elegant way?

*Elegant* is in the eye of the coder.  You might find using one of the many various Git wrappers more elegant.  However, your first method is relatively simple, which has a lot of merit.  We can avoid the new-in-3.7 `capture_output=True` in case someone (*cough* me *cough*) has 3.6 as the base version on their handy test system, and allow use of the shell, which is required for the `$(...)` expansion, which more or less gets us your first attempt.  But we can make use of the fact that `--git-dir` is equivalent to setting `GIT_DIR` in the environment, which means we do not have to do it twice in our command string:

```
import os, subprocess

env = os.environ.copy()
env["GIT_DIR"] = "../micropython/.git"
cmd = "git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1)"
ret = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env=env, shell=True)
```

(using `capture_output=True` as shorthand for the two stdout/stderr is fine, of course, as long as all your Pythons are 3.7 or later).

Note that we must *save the result*.  That's why we have `ret =` here, to capture the result.  We now have the result in `ret`:

```
>>> print(ret)
CompletedProcess(args="git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1)", returncode=0, stdout=b'v2.24.0\n', stderr=b'')
```

Note that the `retcode` is zero—i.e., the thing as a whole worked—and the two `stdout` and `stderr` fields are *bytes* rather than strings.  To fix this, we can either decode the result afterward:

```
>>> print(ret.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
v2.24.0

>>>
```

(which assumes the output is UTF-8) or have `subprocess` do it for us.  The modern (3.7 or later) way to do that is to set `text=True` but since I'm still stuck with 3.6 on this particular machine, I use the older way:

```
ret = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env=env, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

which results in the more useful:

```
>>> print(ret)
CompletedProcess(args="git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1)", returncode=0, stdout='v2.24.0\n', stderr='')
```

Note that using `shell=True` [*requires* that you carefully vet any command you might run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).  [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) also says that on Windows, you get whatever shell is in "the `COMSPEC` environment variable".  It may be wiser to use the default `shell=False` and invoke each component separately:

```
import os, shlex, subprocess

env = os.environ.copy()
env["GIT_DIR"] = "../micropython/.git"

cmd = shlex.split("git rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1")
ret = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=env)
if ret.returncode == 0:
    # Note: I tested this w/o using universal_newlines=True and it
    # worked fine, although the notion of adding a list of bytes to
    # a list of strings seems a bit odd.  This might not work well on
    # Windows; consider adding `text=True` or `universal_newlines=True`
    # above (and again below).
    cmd = shlex.split("git describe --tags") + [ret.stdout.strip()]
    ret = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=env)
```

At this point `ret` is again suitable for inspection: if `ret.returncode` is zero, `ret.stdout` has the byte-string from `git sdescribe`.  Add the appropriate bytes-to-text translation as desired.

```
>>> print(ret)
CompletedProcess(args=['git', 'describe', '--tags', b'da72936f544fec5a335e66432610e4cef4430991'], returncode=0, stdout=b'v2.24.0\n', stderr=b'')
```

If `ret.returncode` is *not* zero, either the `git describe` failed, or the earlier `git rev-list` failed.  You have the failed command in `ret.args`, its status in `ret.returncode`, any stdout text in `ret.stdout`, and any error message from Git in `ret.stderr`.

Comment: i agree with most of what you write; but computer says no :
`CompletedProcess(args="git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags='v[0-9].[0-9]*' --max-count=1)", returncode=129, stdout=b'', stderr=b"error: option `tags' takes no value\n")`  
what is your reference platform ?

Comment: I'm running Git version 2.24 on one machine and 2.20.1 on another. Git acquired support for `--tags=` in commit `b09fe971dea73ff6f5296ce533a566114b23ca4e` way back in 2010, in Git version 1.7.0.

Comment: BTW, looking at your original problem statement, if I read it correctly as "describe the **current** branch", your PowerShell code is overly complicated. What you've got is a way to run `git describe` on the revision selected by enumerating the highest-dated commit in the tags that match the glob pattern you selected. I made the Python code do the same thing as the shell command, I believe.